# Creating a trigger on [msdb].[dbo].restorehistory

Tags: sql, sql-server, restore

I have a requirement to update or change the values of some fields in specific tables when someone restores a Prod database to a Test environment. I just want to change for example 'PROD' characters to 'Test' characters in certain fields once a database have been restored from Prod to Test environment. I have just created a small DB with two tables only and a trigger on `[msdb].[dbo].restorehistory` table, backed up the sample DB to simulate the scenario. But whenever I try restore there is nothing happening on the trigger.

From the below this is what I tried but it seems not working. It looks like the trigger is not hit when there is an [INSERT] event to the table[restorehistory].

```
USE [msdb]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[TriggerA]    Script Date: 12/24/2022 8:22:59 PM ******/

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TriggerA]
ON [msdb].[dbo].[restorehistory]
FOR INSERT
AS

DECLARE @DatabaseName AS VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @DatabaseName = DESTINATION_DATABASE_NAME
FROM INSERTED

IF @DatabaseName='TestDB'

BEGIN
    UPDATE [TestDB].[dbo].<TABLE_X>
        SET FIELD_A     = REPLACE(FIELD_A,'_character_to_replace_','_replace_with_this_character_'), 
            FIELD_B     = REPLACE(FIELD_B,'_character_to_replace_','_replace_with_this_character_') 
        WHERE 
            FIELD_A LIKE '%_character_to_replace_%'

END
```

Please advise if there is something I'm doing wrong or if there is any better alternative.

Comment: FYI, the way your trigger is written assumes that an `INSERT` Only ever effects one row, not many (or 0). Though, honestly, I would never want to put a user trigger on a system table.

Comment: A trigger on [msdb.dbo.restorehistory wont fire](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/06/tracking-restores-hard/).